# Python ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am working on a simple bot for UDP flooding, but it isn't working, all I get when I run is is:

`ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 127.0.0.1`

Here is a snip of what I think is causing the problem:

```
    line = line.split()
    print line
    if(line[0]=='!udp'):
            print "attacking ", line[1]
            udp=socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
            udp.connect((float(line[1]), int(line[2])))
            udp.send(os.urandom(10000))
```

I have searched all around for the error but I cant find anything.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is invalid value for `float`.

Comment: @D4zk1tty I'm glad I was able to answer your question.  It is considered good etiquette (and good karma) to mark answers that help you as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'127.0.0.1' is not a valid floating-point number.  Change `float(line[1])` to `line[1]` and you won't get that error.  You might want to find out what you should be sending as the first argument to `connect` since you can't send an IP in that format as a float.